# Find matching column data between two rows in the same table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to find the matching value between two rows in the same sqlite table. For example, if I have the following table:

```
rowid, col1, col2, col3
-----  ----  ----  ----
1      5     3     1    
2      3     6     9    
3      9     12    5
```

So comparing row 1 and 2, I get the value 3.

- Row 2 and 3 will give 9.
- Row 3 and 1 will give 5.

There will always be one and only one matching value between any two rows in the table.

What it the correct sqlite query for this?

Comment: I don't understand how your matching works. Why do rows 2 and 3 give 9?

Comment: Sorry the first column is the rowid and excluded from the comparison

Comment: And what exactly do you compare?

Comment: The integer value between any two rows. In this case col1, col2, and col3 which contain integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hardcoded the values for the rows because i do not know how to declare variables in sqllite.

```
select t1.rowid as r1, t2.rowid as r2, t2.col as matchvalue from <yourtable> t1 join
(
  select rowid, col1 col from <yourtable> where rowid = 3 union all
  select rowid, col2 from <yourtable> where rowid = 3 union all
  select rowid, col3 from <yourtable> where rowid = 3
) t2
on t2.col in (t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3)
and t1.rowid < t2.rowid -- you don't need this if you have two specific rows
and t1.rowid = 1
```

Comment: `declare`? Does SQLite support this?

Comment: In my table I have 8 columns, so is this query faster than say extracting the column values then assign them to an array and compare using code outside sql?.

Comment: @PutraKg with 8 columns, you need a different script. Answer has been changed.

Comment: Thanks t-clausen. So guys are so helpful. I am actually new to database programming sqlite so hope you can bear with me :). I modified the script and execute the SQl. I get the correct result. But what if I just want to compare any two rows a time?

Comment: @PutraKg I modified the query to compare rowid 1 and 3

Answer (score 0):

```
select col from
(    
    select rid, c1 as col from yourtable
    union
    select rid, c2 from yourtable
    union
    select rid, c3 from yourtable
) v
where rid in (3,2)
group by col
order by COUNT(*) desc
limit 1
```